# Tracking Mobile App User Retention rate using Pandas GroupBy and Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to build a cohort retention graph using `plotly`. So I here's a sample of the first dataset (table name: userjoining):

```
createdAt           trails_count    userId  userName
2018-07-01 00:00:10   0             *****   ******
```

This signifies  when the user has joined, `createdAt` is the datetime when he/she has created an account.

And this a sample of my second dataset (table name: storeactivity) :

```
dateTime             userId
2018-07-01 00:00:00  *****
```

which signifies when the user has  opened the App.

I want to plot a retention graph, like how many users are opening the app till the end of the month, on a weekly as well as daily basis. Here's a link of a sample graph that I want to plot, but on a weekly basis as well, here it is represented on a daily basis. 
Link: https://d35fo82fjcw0y8.cloudfront.net/2017/10/16092847/Phase-1.png

But the thing is that I'm not able to understand how do I merge the two tables and  ``` groupby``userId ``` as well as to understand when they are opening the app, and how they are maintaining their retention till the last week from their date of joining.

Thing is that, everyday someone or the other new user is popping up, so I have to distinguish their weekly retention from their date of acquisition. So any hints or sample code, so that I can get something similar?

Also I want to generate a csv file, of like how many users are opening atleast once every week from their date of acquistion.